# How to insert text with a value from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to insert a text with a value from another table, can it be done in one query?

if I remove (**'value from table2 : ' +**) from the query, the value selected is inserted properly, but when I add it, the value inserted is 0.

```
INSERT INTO table1 ( col1, col2, col3, col4)
VALUES ( 896, 'azer', 'value from table2 : ' + (SELECT table2.col2 FROM table2 WHERE table2.col1 = 5 ), 675)
```

the inserted value in col3 should like this: "value from table2 : zsqd"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use CONCAT function for concatenation.

```
INSERT INTO table1 ( col1, col2, col3, col4) 
VALUES ( 896, 'azer', (SELECT CONCAT('value from table2 :',table2.col2) FROM table2 WHERE table2.col1 = 5 ), 675)
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple

If `col3` in `table1` is varchar or text then try this

`INSERT INTO table1 ( col1, col2, col3, col4)
VALUES ( 896, 'azer', (SELECT CONCAT("value from table2 : ",table2.col2) FROM table2 WHERE table2.col1 = 5 ), 675)`